# How to distort a subdivided plane to fit round mesh edge?

Tags: mesh

So I'm trying to get this triangle
[image]

To fit around the curve of the parallel edge without shaping it manually, making the entire thing curve to fit instead of just snapping the vertices at the top.
Another angle for reference: [image]

Comment: You could try joining those together since the vertices align by filling or merging and then just delete/adjust the edge of the triangle, this should get the curvature you're going for.

Comment: That would curve the top of the triangle, but I'm trying to make the entire triangle match the curve of the edge rather than just the top.

Comment: You could use the same instructions and play with rotating from a fixed point, say the tip of the triangle with proportional editing on.

Comment: How do I rotate around the vertex at the point?